# Android Application force closes. (NullPointerException / ToggleButton)

Tags: android

My Code:

```
public class My_Application extends Activity {

public ToggleButton privBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.privacyShow);
public LinearLayout privLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.privacyLayout);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    privBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(privBtn.isChecked()) {
                privLay.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                privLay.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

---

When I launch the application it force closes. I debugged the application with the built-in Dev Tools application in the emulator, and see the following:

```
[2011-06-23 20:27:06 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:572)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:671)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

As well as a "Source not found." error at:

```
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2417
```

---

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="My Application" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textSize="25dp" android:background="#222" />

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
>
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="  Server IP: " android:textSize="20dp" android:textColor="#0F0"
android:layout_weight="0.7" />
<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="eg: 0.0.0.0" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:textSize="20dp"
android:id="@+id/loginIP" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
>
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Server Port: " android:textSize="20dp" android:textColor="#0F0"
android:layout_weight="0.7" />
<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="eg: 1234" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:textSize="20dp"
android:id="@+id/loginPort" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/privacyLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Privacy Options" android:textSize="20dp" android:textColor="#0F0"
android:layout_weight="0.4" />
<ToggleButton android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:checked="false" android:layout_weight="0.6" android:textOff="Show Options"
android:textOn="Hide Options" android:id="@+id/privacyShow" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="invisible"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="20dp">
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Username: " android:textColor="#0F0" android:textSize="15dp"
android:layout_weight="0.5" />
<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="30dp"
android:id="@+id/privacyUsername" android:textSize="15dp" android:layout_weight="0.2" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Password: " android:textColor="#0F0" android:textSize="15dp"
android:layout_weight="0.5" />
<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="30dp"
android:id="@+id/privacyPassword" android:textSize="15dp" android:layout_weight="0.2" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the privBtn and privLay before the `setContentView()` is called.  Move those two statements into your `onCreate()`.

```
public class My_Application extends Activity {

    public ToggleButton privBtn;
    public LinearLayout privLay;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        privBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.privacyShow);
        privLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.privacyLayout);

        privBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(privBtn.isChecked()) {
                    privLay.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    privLay.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: in addition, if you want them globally declare them up front and just assign them in the `onCreate()`

Comment: ^^ Right.  And you'll definitely need the privLay at least to have the scope of your Activity so that you can use it in the OnClickListener.  Edited to provide an example with code.

Comment: Can you post main.xml?  Putting the statements before the `onCreate()` was definitely a problem.

Comment: Edited main post. (added main.xml)

Comment: After making the changes above, the `NullPointerException` is resolved, and it runs perfectly for me.  I suggest cleaning your project (Project -> Clean in Eclipse).

Comment: I cleaned the project and it forced closed again for about 1.5 seconds, but then started fine...any idea why?

Comment: Not sure, honestly.  You're definitely not the only person that's gotten this error, but I don't see any solutions to it or explanations of it anywhere.  Eclipse quirk?  I have problems with it on occasion.

Comment: No problem, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you receive an answer that satisfies you, we greatly appreciate it if you accept it as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. :)